# eager loading access the pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, eager-loading

i have 3 models

1-book:

```
class Book extends Model
{
protected $guarded=[];
public function users(){return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);}  
public function bookUser(){return $this->hasMany(BookUser::class);} 
}
```

2-user

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
protected $guarded = [];
public function books(){return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);}
```

3-bookuser

```
class BookUser extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];
protected $table = 'book_user';
public function book(){return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);}
public function user(){return $this->belongsTo(User::class) ; }
}
```

bookuser migrations:

```
Schema::create('book_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->boolean('like')->nullable()->default(0);
    });
```

i am trying to get all the books with the likes of just the current user:

```
public function index()
{
    id=Auth::user()->id;
    $books=Book::with('users')->get();
    return response()->json($books);   
}
```

this is what i got:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-03-22T14:16:30.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-22T14:16:30.000000Z",
    "name": "power",
    "image": "978014444447899.jpg",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "mark",
            "type": "reader",
            "image": null,
            "created_at": "2021-03-22T13:59:26.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-22T13:59:26.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "book_id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-03-22T14:20:26.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-03-22T14:39:56.000000Z",
                "like": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

how can i access the pivot table...or how to get that like?? am trying this but id doesn't work

```
 $id=Auth::user()->id;
    
    $books=Book::with('users',function($query) {
    return $query->where('user.id','=',$id);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to inject the `$id` to the function scope with `use`

```
$id=Auth::user()->id;
    
$books=Book::with(['users' => function($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('user.id','=',$id);
}])->get();
```

Comment: gives me this
TypeError: mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given in file

Comment: i changed it to user_id .. it works finally!!
Thanks alot Man.